# Could not find method "method" in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class MaterialButton with id "id"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to get this button to launch a block of code but it can't seem to find it.
This is a button in a fragment that is trying to launch another fragment inside a single activity architecture.

[Method that gets called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEz7v.png) (Notice how it's greyed out)

[Button that calls the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBYjv.png)

[Android complaining that this doesn't exist yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD4wv.png)

[Design properties seeing function just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2qQT.png)

[Error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIguA.png)

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is enough context here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to my problem was to just set up the calls programmatically vs in layout for fragments. Using a setOnClickListener with the binding in onCreateView worked. If you are using a binding, make sure to return binding.root in the onCreateView, or else it won't work.